# Compare 1st element of list from nest list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists like following :

```
[[a1,a2], [b1,b2],....,  [n1]]
```

and I want to find whether the first elements of all these lists are equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd prefer to do this with a list comprehension unless there's a reason to avoid it, for readability's sake.

```
list_of_lists = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
len(set([sublist[0] for sublist in list_of_lists])) == 1
# True
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is quite straight forward.

1. Transpose your list. Use `zip` to perform this task
2. Index the first row of your transposed list
3. Use set to remove duplicate
4. Determine if no of elements is equal to 1

---

```
>>> test = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
>>> len(set(zip(*test)[0])) == 1
True
```

**Note**

If you are using Py 3.X, instead of slicing, wrap the call to `zip` with `next`

```
>>> len(set(next(zip(*test)))) == 1
```

Comment: In my tests this consistently slightly outperforms `set(map(itemgetter...`. Its performance vs. `all` is similar to `set(map(itemgetter...`, beating it when the first failure is around halfway into the list and performing much worse on an early failure. On Python 3 you must wrap `zip` in a call to `list` before slicing, or using `itertools.islice`.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper: I would refrain from micro optimization, unless its a bottleneck and my outlook is, what matters is readability.

Comment: To my eye the `all` version is the most readable, but opinions can reasonably differ there.

Answer (score 1):

How about?

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> test = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
>>> len(set(map(itemgetter(0), test))) == 1
True
>>> test.append([2, 5])
>>> test
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 5]]
>>> len(set(map(itemgetter(0), test))) == 1
False
```

And another way would be (Thanks, Peter DeGlopper!)

```
all(sublist[0] == test[0][0] for sublist in test)
```

This version would short-circuit too, so it wouldn't need to check every element in every case.

Comment: I think this is more naturally expressed as `all(sublist[0] == test[0][0] for sublist in test)`. Or, to get out of one-liner land, `first = test[0][0]; all(sublist[0] == first for sublist in test)`

Comment: I haven't profiled, so I'm running the risk of asserting something that would not be true when tested, but I would be surprised to see a meaningful performance difference from the short-circuiting. Set construction is fast.

Comment: I think otherwise. For very very large lists, set construction would need to traverse every element (even if the incorrect element is at the start) and then hash them all. While `all` with an iterator would short circuit faster.

Comment: It will definitely depend on the data, and how early a failure appears compared to the size of the input list of lists. `all` is definitely theoretically better, but I think the constructors for builtins are more optimized. I ran one quick test case with a 1000-length list of identical 2-element sublists, and in fact the `set` approach finished 10k repetitions twice as fast as the `all` approach - 0.75 seconds as opposed to 1.5 seconds. At the other extreme, if test[1][0] differs the `set` approach obviously takes the same time, but `all` takes 0.03 seconds. Not sure how deep for `all` to win.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper: Looks like the OP would have to choose between the two choices according to what his data is, then.

Comment: One more datapoint, with the first failure halfway through the list `set` is very marginally faster - still around 0.75 seconds for 10k checks, compared to around 0.8 seconds for `all`. All calculated on my PC on Python 3.4, the C implementation. This is probably not the top thing to optimize given how fast both are, I'm just easily distracted by this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of first elements compared to the first sublist's first element:

```
False not in [len(yourList[0])>0 and len(x)>0 and x[0] == yourList[0][0] for x in yourList]
```

Answer (score 0):

With a one liner:

```
>>> sample = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x if x == y[0] else None, sample, sample[0][0])
1
>>> sample = [[0, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x if x == y[0] else None, sample, sample[0][0])
None
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
>>> test = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
>>> eval("==".join(map(lambda x: str(x[0]), test)))
True
```

Comment: There are so many ways to do this that I cannot possibly see sanctioning the use of `eval`, which is unsafe unless run over entirely trusted input. The input in this case may be trusted, but `eval` is completely unnecessary. If you want to implement this approach safely, use `reduce(operator.eq, (map(operator.itemgetter(0), test)))`. Or `reduce(operator.eq, (sublist[0] for sublist in test))`. I think both are harder to read than the `all` or `set` approaches, but at least they're safe.

Comment: @Peter DeGlopper: Yes... Using `eval` is unsafe. I didn't care about security because I'm not serious in this case but I just think this code slightly readable. And your another approach to use `operator.eq` is very good. I didn't know that. Thanks. :)